# The validity of a university degree from Iran

Tags: phd

How can I find out how valid my degree from the Iranian University of Applied Sciences is in America?

Comment: What degree? Do you mean you have a doctorate from there? Valid for what purpose? Graduate admissions? Academic jobs?

Comment: The US does not have a centralized system for recognition of degrees.  Each institution will decide for itself.

Comment: The university I'm studying at has a global ranking of #783I wanted to apply for graduate studies, but I don't know if a university like Stanford will accept me? Yes, I know there are people from Iran who can get admission, but they studied in very good Iranian universities. Do I stand a chance of admission with a degree from a regular university? Is the university where I got my bachelor's degree important, or is it important to have a resume and an essay for admission to graduate school?

Answer (score 4):

It'll be great if you specify what valid means in your case. If you mean valid for applying for Ph.D. degrees in the US, then yes. I had many peers during my studies who held undergraduate degrees from Iranian Universities. Especially in STEM fields. I also knew of Iranians who worked in the IT industry, holding undergraduate degrees from Iran.

Comment: The university I'm studying at has a global ranking of #783... I wanted to apply for graduate studies, but I don't know if a university like Stanford will accept me? Yes, I know there are people from Iran who can get admission, but they studied in very good Iranian universities. Do I stand a chance of admission with a degree from a regular university? Is the university where I got my bachelor's degree important, or is it important to have a resume and an essay for admission to graduate school?

Comment: Hi! Back when I was applying for graduate school (I studied at a University in Europe that is considered the best in the country but not so famous worldwide), what mattered most for admission were the GRE scores (subject and general), the interest you had in the program, and any research experience. Please don't apply to Stanford bc it's Stanford, apply to schools that interest you in terms of their research programs. Also please apply to many schools and include some safety schools in your application!

Comment: Thank you for your good guide and help